# Arabic letters not connecting in annotated string created with AnnotatedString.Builder()

Tags: android, kotlin, fonts, android-jetpack-compose

Using AnnotatedString.Builder to create an annotated string to be displayed in a basic text field, the Arabic letters of the string do not connect like they should.

I am building an Android Jetpack Compose app that allows the user to enter a string of text. It randomizes the fonts of each character of the string between three custom fonts. I use AnnotatedString.Builder() to achieve this:

```
fun buildAnnotatedStringWithFonts(text:String): AnnotatedString{

    val builder = AnnotatedString.Builder()

    for (i in text.indices) {
        val character = text[i].toString()
        builder.withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontFamily = mlalahFonts.random())) {
            append(character)
        }
    }
    return builder.toAnnotatedString()
}
```

this function is used in the following class:

```
class FontsTransformation : VisualTransformation {
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        return TransformedText(
            buildAnnotatedStringWithFonts(text.toString()),
            OffsetMapping.Identity)
    }
}
```

Which is in turn used by the following composable:

```
BasicTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    textStyle = TextStyle(
        color = ComposeColor.Black,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        fontSize = 40.sp,
    ),
    visualTransformation = FontsTransformation(),
)
```

The issue is that the letters which are typed in (in Arabic) [do not connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4DWn.png). This happens regardless of the font used. Using a default serif font with `builder.withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif))` [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYHCM.png) is the result.

The problem is probably with `buildAnnotatedStringWithFonts` but I'm not sure what the solution is.  Can Kotlin/Android/Compose connect Arabic characters which have different fonts?

Comment: It's just probably not plausible. I just tried assigning a different font to each letter in Microsoft Word and the same thing happened!

Comment: @Prs2 I tried it libreoffice myself and it worked, but who knows if compose has the ability. Like I showed the letters do not connect when I set the letters to the same font using AnnotatedString.Builder() either so I think there's an issue there.

Comment: I don't have libreoffice to check but I'm surprised this can work anywhere. Connected letters are called ligatures, and the ligatures are defined within a typeface. I don't know how a ligature could possibly work across two typefaces.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Arabic letters don't connect using ligatures except for one sequence of two letters. That's why this can work. The question is if there is another way to write buildAnnotatedStringWithFonts() which would avoid the problem of disconnected letters. Again, this happens even if all the letters have the same font.